# How to select a set of fields from input data as an array of repeated fields in beam SQL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-calcite, beam-sql

Problem Statement:

I  have  an  input  PCollection  with  following  fields:

```
{
   firstname_1,
   lastname_1,
   dob,
   firstname_2,
   lastname_2, 
   firstname_3,
   lastname_3,
}
```

then I execute a Beam SQL  operation such that output of resultant  PCollection should be like

```
 ----------------------------------------------
   name.firstname |  name.lastname | dob
 ---------------------------------------------- 
      firstname_1 |  lastname_1    | 202009
      firstname_2 |  lastname_2    | 
      firstname_3 |  lastname_3    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

To be precise:

```
array[
    (firstname_1,lastname_1,dob),
    (firstname_2,lastname_2,dob),
    (firstname_3,lastname_3,dob)
]
```

Here is the code snippet where I execute Beam SQL:

```java
PCollectionTuple tuple=
    PCollectionTuple.of(new TupleTag<>("testPcollection"), testPcollection);

PCollection<Row> result = tuple
    .apply(SqlTransform.query(
        "SELECT array[(firstname_1,lastname_1,dob), (firstname_2,lastname_2,dob), (firstname_3,lastname_3,dob)]"));
```

I am not getting proper results.

Can someone guide  me  how to query an array of repeated field in Beam  SQL?

Comment: What was the output that you got?

Comment: Can you write out the full schema of your input, including types, the full schema of your desired output, including types, and the exact rows and values you want in the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this example on how to access arrays in Beam SQL - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d110f6b7610b26edc1eb9a4b698840b21c151847/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslNestedRowsTest.java#L234

Comment: hi i   just  had  a  look  at  the  link  which  u  shared  ,  in  the  example  mentioned  in  link  input   schema  itself  is  having   an  array  type,  but  solution  that  i  am  trying  to  find is  :  input  schema  will  be  normal  set  of  fields,  and  output  schema  will  have  array  type  where  fields  from  input  will  be  grouped  under  them , can  u  help  pls  help  me  on  this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has a few errors.

1. You have named the input to the SQL query `testPcollection`. Your SQL query does not select `FROM testPcollection`. Let us assume you meant it to be `FROM testPcollection`.
2. You use the syntax `(firstname_1, lastname_1, doc)` in both your expected output and your query. This is not any valid SQL expression.

Comment: hi  can  u  guide  me   what  will   actual  sql  expression  for  this,  i  am  pretty  new  to  beam  sql

Comment: I cannot really tell what output you are expecting.